# params.isZoomSupported() is returning false in Samsung galaxy SIII mini

Tags: android

params.isZoomSupported() is returning false in custom camera in Samsung galaxy SIII but it supports zooming when I access default camera and the same code works fine in Samsung Tablet.
 does anybody know why it is the case.
 And here is my code

public void setZoomControl(final Camera.Parameters params) {

```
    System.out.println("setZoomControl called");
    if (params.isZoomSupported()) {
        final int maxZoomLevel = params.getMaxZoom();
        Log.i("max ZOOM ", "is " + maxZoomLevel);
        zoomControls.setIsZoomInEnabled(true);
        zoomControls.setIsZoomOutEnabled(true);

        zoomControls.setOnZoomInClickListener(new OnClickListener(){


            public void onClick(View v){
                if(currentZoomLevel < maxZoomLevel){
                    currentZoomLevel++;
                    //mCamera.startSmoothZoom(currentZoomLevel);
                    params.setZoom(currentZoomLevel);
                    mCamera.setParameters(params);
                }
            }
        });

        zoomControls.setOnZoomOutClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v){
                if(currentZoomLevel > 0){
                    currentZoomLevel--;
                    params.setZoom(currentZoomLevel);
                    mCamera.setParameters(params);
                }
            }
        });    
    }
    else
    {
        zoomControls.setVisibility(View.GONE);
         System.out.println("setZoomControl called not supported");
    }

}
```

Comment: What does params.isSmoothZoomSupported() return?

Comment: even that is returning false

Comment: Well then they have not provided a public API for their zoom methods. You can look around the net for the specific methods they use and use reflection to invoke them, but that's going to slow down your app a bit and isn't guaranteed to work after an update of the device's OS.